# QML Transition not working inside Repeater

Tags: qt, animation, qml, transition, repeater

I am trying to move an item in my QML off-screen using a transition with `AnchorChanges`, like so:

```js
Item {
   id: view

   Repeater {
      id: repeater
      model: 1

      Rectangle {
         id: card
         property int index
         color: "red"
         radius: 10

         width: parent.width * 0.9
         height: parent.height * 0.7

         anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
         anchors.top: parent.top
         anchors.topMargin: units.gu(8)

         states: [
            State {
               name: "hidden"
               AnchorChanges { target: card; anchors.top: view.bottom }
            }
         ]

         transitions: Transition {
             AnchorAnimation { duration: 5000 }
         }

         Component.onCompleted: card.state = "hidden"
       }
   }
}
```

I am using a `Repeater` because there will be several cards, which I want to move off-screen.

However, when I use the `Repeater` as shown above, there will be no animation. Instead, after a delay of 5 seconds, the card will be instantly hidden.

If I instead remove the repeater, the animation will be shown:

```js
Item {
   id: view

   Rectangle {
      id: card
      property int index
      color: "red"
      radius: 10

      width: parent.width * 0.9
      height: parent.height * 0.7

      anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
      anchors.top: parent.top
      anchors.topMargin: units.gu(8)

      states: [
         State {
            name: "hidden"
            AnchorChanges { target: card; anchors.top: view.bottom }
         }
      ]

      transitions: Transition {
          AnchorAnimation { duration: 5000 }
      }

      Component.onCompleted: card.state = "hidden"
    }
}
```

Whats the reason for this?

Comment: I don't quite understand. In the second example, the card moves smoothly downwards over a duration of 5 seconds.
In the example above, it doesn't. So why can't anchors be animated smoothly? 
I am using a property `topAnchor` because I am stacking several cards on top of each other, with each card anchoring to the card below. I am doing this because I could not find a way to add/modify states via JS, and within the `Repeater`code, the previous card (which should be anchored to) is not know so I cannot set the `AnchorChanges` anchor to the previous card directly.

Comment: You are right, the topAnchor stuff was probably confusing with some of the code missing. It would not matter anyway with only one card being displayed. I have edited the code examples, they should now work for you.

Comment: @folibis, The whole point of an `AnchorAnimation` object is to animate anchors.

Comment: @user826955 What version of Qt are you using? I tried it with 5.15.0 and both of your examples animated for me.

Comment: I deeply apologize for misleading you, the `AnchorAnimation`  is indeed intended for animation. Anyway, both of examples not work for me in Qt 6.0. The example from the `AnchorAnimation` page works but in opposite direction. So I guess that `AnchorAnimation` not so suitable for the issue due to limited control. and apologize again.

Comment: @folibis No worries :)
@JarMan I am on Ubuntu Touch, nit 100% sure, but I think its 5.11 or 5.12. I don't think its a general lack of feature in my version, but rather something is wrong in the code. I can animate a single card, and I can also animate the whole stack of cards by doing the transition outside of `Item`in the above example. This item is a custom view which shall display a stack of cards, upon selecting one card, all others shall be moved off-screen so only one card is displayed. Is there another way to achieve this other than using the code above?

Comment: @user826955, I tried it with version 5.12.5 too, and it still works fine for me.

Comment: It's weird. I tried several other methods, and inside the repeater it would always behave very weird. E.g. I added a `Rectangle` as sibling to the Card, and anchored to this rect in the state. As a result the animation would work for a fraction of the time, then the animation would stop. Maybe it is indeed some kind of bug within either QT or even Lomiri.
In the end I gave up and just skipped the animation part; the cards will now just disappear. What a pity.